# Referring to the public root in PHP - best practices

Tags: php

I've been using the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] environment variable to refer to the public root in my apps. Now I'm realizing that that's not very reliable. I'm thinking about an approach where I define a constant in my index.php based on a magic constant. Something like that:

```
define("PUBILC", __DIR__."/");
```

I'm not sure about it though.

What approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything request goes through your index.php, defining a constant there would be a fine, and often used, idea. I've also seen setups defining an environmental variable with (virtual)host configuration or .htaccess, but I think its less transparent and less portable. Hardcoding paths in a settings variable is often used but less 'altering automatically' then one would hope. All in all I agree with your idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question if I may. What do you think would be an accurate and short name for a constant referring to the public root? I'm not sure about "PUBLIC".

Comment: Yes, all requests go through my index.php.

Comment: YOURAPPNAME_ROOT would be most applicable, and with the least change of hitting another constant defined in other packages. Assuming you have a relatively unique name for your project.

Comment: Safety & readability trump shortness, let your editor autocomplete it if you don't feel like typing it again & again.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely don't have `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` scattered throughout your application. Apache can be configured to use `VirtualDocumentRoot` which will set the document root to that directory but that will **not** change the DOCUMENT_ROOT environment variable which can lead to broken sites.

In line with your approach, I like to define `DOC_ROOT` at the top of my app and use that anywhere I need to refer to the document root.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar, but put it in some common include file that gets included in all your pages. That works for visitors that come directly to a page on your site without going through the main index page.

For example, if you've got `utilities.php` in your `doc_root/inc` folder, and it gets included in all your site pages, it might look something like this:

```
<?php
function GetDocumentRoot()
{
    return dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
}

function WriteHeader()
{
    //...
}

// more utility functions...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In one os my projects I have made a config with the following lines (and some additional ones):

```
// set the root directory for the files
define('ROOT_DIR', "/path/to/my/htdocs/project_name/");
// set the root path for URLs
define('ROOT_PATH', "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/project_name/");
```

Within every php file I then include this config.php using this line:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config_project_name.php');
```

As you can see using a prefix for the config files, you can put them all into your root directory and you are still flexible enough to have the same project on different PCs or servers.